# MVC Entity Framework - Foreign Keys from multiple tables in one field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird, ef-fluent-api

So I'm building an interface for an existing program, that is built on top of a firebird database. I've generated some models using the data provider for firebird, and I'm trying to define the relationship between a few tables that have an odd structure, which I cant change without breaking the program.

This is the current structure boiled down:

```
public partial class JOBLINE
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int JobNumber {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LineNumber {get;set;}
    public string LineType {get;set;} // can be either 'Item Code' or 'Descriptor Code'
    public string LineCode {get;set;}
}

public partial class ITEMMASTER
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemCode {get;set;}
    // The other properties
}

public partial class DESCRIPTORMASTER
{
    [Key]
    public string DescriptorCode {get;set;}
    // The other properties
}
```

So the annoying thing is that in the `jobline` table, the `LineCode` field can contain the foreign key for either `ItemMaster` or `DescriptorMaster`, depending on what the `CodeType` field contains.

Is there an easy way to specify this? Either using the fluent API or data annotations. I'm hoping to have List accessors for the `ItemMaster` and `DescriptorMaster` tables

Answer (score 2):

> So the annoying thing is that in the jobline table, the LineCode field
>   can contain the foreign key for either ItemMaster, or
>   DescriptorMaster, depending on what the CodeType field contains.

Are you sure your database (which is Firebird) allows that kind of thing?

Databases that use the relational concept do not allow a foreign key column to contain a value from different table. A foreign key is here to make relationship between two tables not more.

In your situation the only thing you can do is to create an unique constraint that will combine those two columns: `LineType` and `LineCode`.

So you can use `Index` data annotation attribute like below:

```
public partial class JOBLINE
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int JobNumber {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LineNumber {get;set;}

    [Index("IX_LineTypeAndLineCode", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string LineType {get;set;} 

    [Index("IX_LineTypeAndLineCode", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string LineCode {get;set;}
}
```

Or use fluent configuration like below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JOBLINE>()
    .Property(p => p.LineType)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_LineTypeAndLineCode") { IsUnique = true, Order = 1 }));

modelBuilder.Entity<JOBLINE>()
    .Property(p => p.LineCode)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_LineTypeAndLineCode") { IsUnique = true, Order = 2 }));
```

With unique constraint you make sure that foreach each `LineType` value in `JOBLINE` table there is an unique value for `LineCode`.

Comment: Thanks. How would I handle designating the relationship?

Comment: There is no need to add a relashionship Think the unique constraint as a guard about data that are inserted to the combineed columns. As I said in the answer you can't create a relashionship between three tables like you need to do with shared columns. It's impossible.